# Finding a specific value in any column

Tags: r

```
COL1 COL2 COLn
113  543  321
842  113  923
234  643  412
```

I have a dataset called “A" consisting of thousands of columns (COL1 ... COLn) and with thousands of rows. I want to find every instance of a specific value like “113”, for example, in any column.

I tried `sum(A == 113)` and this works with a smaller version of the data set but not a large one. With the larger version the data set I get NA as an answer.

Comment: did you try with `sum( A == 113, na.rm=T)`?

Comment: oh....my....god.... that was it... thank you